# how to change center of canvas.drawArc android in a custom view

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, center, android-custom-view

[image][image]I got code for creating a custom view to show gauge in android.

```
public class CustomGauge extends View {

private static final int DEFAULT_LONG_POINTER_SIZE = 1;

private Paint mPaint;
private float mStrokeWidth;
private int mStrokeColor;
private RectF mRect;
private String mStrokeCap;
private int mStartAngel;
private int mSweepAngel;
private int mStartValue;
private int mEndValue;
private int mValue;
private double mPointAngel;
private float mRectLeft;
private float mRectTop;
private float mRectRight;
private float mRectBottom;
private int mPoint;
private int mPointColor;
private float mPointSize;
private int mPointStartColor;
private int mPointEndColor;

public CustomGauge(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public CustomGauge(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    Log.v("SSS", "in CustomGauge");
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomGauge, 0, 0);

    // stroke style
    mStrokeWidth = a.getDimension(R.styleable.CustomGauge_strokeWidth, 10);
    mStrokeColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CustomGauge_strokeColor, android.R.color.darker_gray);
    mStrokeCap = a.getString(R.styleable.CustomGauge_strokeCap);

    // angel start and sweep (opposite direction 0, 270, 180, 90)
    mStartAngel = a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomGauge_startAngel, 0);
    mSweepAngel = a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomGauge_sweepAngel, 360);

    // scale (from mStartValue to mEndValue)
    mStartValue = a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomGauge_startValue, 0);
    mEndValue = a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomGauge_endValue, 1000);

    // pointer size and color
    mPointSize = 0.3f;// a.getColor(R.styleable.CustomGauge_pointSize, 0);
    mPointStartColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CustomGauge_pointStartColor, android.R.color.white);
    mPointEndColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CustomGauge_pointEndColor, android.R.color.white);

    // calculating one point sweep
    mPointAngel = ((double) Math.abs(mSweepAngel) / (mEndValue - mStartValue));
    a.recycle();
    init();
}

private void init() {
    Log.v("SSS", "in init");
    // main Paint
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(mStrokeColor);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(mStrokeWidth);
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mStrokeCap)) {
        if (mStrokeCap.equals("BUTT"))
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);
        else if (mStrokeCap.equals("ROUND"))
            mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    } else
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mRect = new RectF();

    mValue = mStartValue;
    mPoint = mStartAngel;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Log.v("SSS", "in CustomGauge");
    float paddingLeft = getPaddingLeft();
    float paddingRight = getPaddingRight();
    float paddingTop = getPaddingTop();
    float paddingBottom = getPaddingBottom();
    float width = getWidth() - (paddingLeft + paddingRight);
    float height = getHeight() - (paddingTop + paddingBottom);
    float radius = (width > height ? width / 2 : height / 2) * 3/8;

    mRectLeft = width / 2 - radius + paddingLeft;
    mRectTop = height / 2 - radius + paddingTop;
    // mRectRight = width / 2 - radius + paddingLeft + width;
    mRectRight = width / 2 - radius + paddingLeft + width;
    mRectBottom = height / 2 - radius + paddingTop + height;
    // Log.v("SSS", "mRectLeft:" + mRectLeft + "    mRectTop:" + mRectTop +
    // "    mRectRight:" + mRectRight + "   mRectBottom:" + mRectBottom);

    mRect.set(mRectLeft, mRectTop, mRectRight, mRectBottom);

    mPaint.setColor(mStrokeColor);
    mPaint.setShader(null);
    // canvas.drawArc(mRect, mStartAngel, mSweepAngel, false, mPaint);//
    // this draws the background arc
    mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
    mPaint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, getHeight(), mPointEndColor, mPointStartColor, android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
    canvas.drawArc(mRect, mPoint - mPointSize / 2, mPointSize, true, mPaint);
    Log.v("SSS" , "mPoint:" + mPoint + ".........mPointSize:" + mPointSize);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, 15, paint);
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    mValue = value;
    mPoint = (int) (mStartAngel + (mValue - mStartValue) * mPointAngel);
    invalidate();
}

public int getValue() {
    return mValue;
}
```

}

And layout code is,

```
 <pl.pawelkleczkowski.customgauge.example.CustomGauge
    android:background="@drawable/cluster"
    android:id="@+id/gauge1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    gauge:pointStartColor="@color/Red"
    gauge:pointEndColor="@color/Red"
    gauge:pointSize="1"
    gauge:startAngel="180"
    gauge:strokeCap="ROUND"
    gauge:strokeColor="@color/Gray"
    gauge:strokeWidth="10dp"
    gauge:startValue="0"
    gauge:endValue="1000"
    gauge:sweepAngel="180" />
```

In activity I used that like

```
gauge1 = (CustomGauge) findViewById(R.id.gauge1);
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                        try {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    gauge1.setValue(i * 10);
                                    }
                            });
                            Thread.sleep(10);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

Using this I'm successfully showing a gauge.

But issue is, in `onDraw` method of Custeom view, the canvas is drawing the arc using `canvas.drawArc` with it's center at center position of that custom view in layout.

But I want to change the center of `canvas.drawArc` so that, the arc drawn in my custom view will have center at bottom of that entire custom view.

So how to change the center around which the arc will be drawn in above case.

Comment: see the first "oval" parameter, it defines the bounds of the arc

Comment: What is output and what you required, if you add some image then it will be very easy to understand

Comment: added image, @pskink the first oval parameter is the bounds of the rectangle on that arc. Changing that is going to change only the width of the arc. And I passed the fourth parameter as true so that line is getting shown. But I want to change the center from where the line will start, I want it at bottom of entire custom view

Comment: rect has four sides: left,  top,  right and bottom,  not just width and height, if you want it to be drawn on the bottom increase top and bottom sides

Comment: @pskink no it doesn't work like that. That rect is inside that arc. The line, which is drawn, connects the center and that rect on that arc because of the fourth param true, without that u don't even see the line but just the arc. So there is no relation between that rect and center

Comment: center of the arc is always in the center of the rect (the first parameter of drawArc method), this is the relation

Comment: @pskink please see the modified image

Comment: i dont understand what you mean on your images, maybe this one will make it clear: http://snag.gy/WIZAj.jpg, as you can see the center of the "oval" and the arc itself is directly in the center of the "rect"

Answer (score 0):

I just found an upvote to the question, so putting the answer(work around) that I found out

```
canvas.scale(1, 2.0f);
```

This moved canvas drawing position from center of image to bottom of image.(Only y axis shifted).